# 12 to 3V DC/DC conversion at 1A

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter

I need to convert 12V input power to 3V (not 3.3).  The output current needs to be 1A or better.

My gut-reaction was to get an off-the-shelf DC/DC, but it doesn't look like there are any commercially available that provide 3V at anywhere close to the current output I need.

I also need short circuit (over current) protection on the output side.

Design space of this PCB is limited.  It will also be hand-assembled, so SMDs with pads under the part are not an option, through-hole would be preferred.

I don't need a complete solution, just an expert to steer me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: The right direction is Digi-Key or Mouser, and select desirable filters. Or you can go to TI.com and plug your numbers into their design configurator, it will give you a list of suitable devices to work with. Clearly you haven't done any legwork. And please forget about "through hole", this technology has died. There is nothing difficult to hand assemble SMT parts.

Comment: ??? no 3-V adjustable DC-DC converters at 1A? Are you serious? Just look at eBay, you will find dozens, for $1-$2 a piece.

Comment: There are tons of little ready-made DC-DC modules by Murata, traco etc on digikey, mouser, farnell, which fit your requirements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you are looking for a buck converter. While many buck converters show applications for 3.3 volts due to the popularity of this voltage, many are in fact adjustable.

As an example take a look at the LTC3824. You will see the app notes show 3.3 volts but take note of the resistive divider on the output connected to V<sub>FB</sub>. This is what sets the regulated output voltage. Simply adjust the divide ratio and you have a 3 volt regulator capable of sourcing 2 amps.

Take note that this chip, as do others, has current monitoring that can foldback the output voltage if excess current is sensed. This is accomplished via a shunt resistor connected to the SENSE input.

Answer (score 1):

My gut reaction is that at only an amp of output, any number of integrated switch buck chips should suffice, LT or TI would be my instinctive starting point (in that order if only building a few, I like the LT datasheets more then the TI ones, and webbench sometimes offers really weird suggestions).

The LT1375 looks on a quick glance to be suitable for example, but there are many, many good options.